# Perspective Camera zooming between finger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know how to program a zoomable (between fingers) perspective camera in unity?

There are tons of tutorial out there that program a normal zooming to the center camera. 
But it seems I am unable to find a C# tutorial on how to "zooming between finger" feature in perspective camera.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for "Pinch and zoom" with Unity.

The basic idea is to use multi touch inputs from Unity api and then change your camera's size (if its orthographic) or field of view (if perspective) based on the pinch magnitude.

[Tutorial 1](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/pinch-zoom)

[Tutorial 2](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/unity3d-panning-and-pinch-to-zoom-camera-with-touch-and-mouse-input)